# Using cursor in T-SQL - Leaves column in last row of result NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quick Question,

So I created a cursor I use on a medical database that will display all the billing codes (CPT codes) for a specific encounter (Voucher) on one line. The reason for this is an encounter can have many billing codes, and the encounter > billing code table relationship is a one to many. So if an encounter has 3 billing codes, there will be 3 lines in the result set , one for each code.

Lets say for example I have :

```
    Voucher_Number          CPT 

    1                       A

    1                       B

    1                       C

    2                       Z

    2                       X

    2                       Y

    3                       P

    3                       Q

    3                       S
```

The code I am currently using using will end up with these results :

```
    Voucher_Number         CPT  


    1                      A, B, C 

    2                      Z, X, Y, 

    3                      NULL
```

This is the cursor I am currently using , the temp table #VoucherData has a line for each unique combination of Voucher_Number and CPT

I am sure this is something so simple I am missing here, this code was given to me by someone else before they left and he said he never bothered to fix it, that for that last line to just manually look up the codes (This isn't part of an application we are just dumping the results into a Excel File)

```
/* Cursor FOR CPT CODES */

DECLARE @CPTTABLE TABLE (voucher_number INT , cptcode varchar(255))
DECLARE @CPT varchar(max)
DECLARE @CPTCODE varchar(50)
DECLARE @CPTVOUCHER INT
DECLARE @CURRENTCPTVOUCHER INT
DECLARE CPTCURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT Voucher_Number, CPT FROM #VoucherData ORDER BY Voucher_Number, CPT

OPEN CPTCURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM CPTCURSOR INTO @CPTVOUCHER, @CPTCODE
SET @CURRENTCPTVOUCHER=@CPTVOUCHER
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN 
  IF @CURRENTCPTVOUCHER<>@CPTVOUCHER
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @CPTTABLE VALUES(@CURRENTCPTVOUCHER, @CPT) 
    SET @CPT=NULL 
    SET @CURRENTCPTVOUCHER=@CPTVOUCHER 
  END 

  SET @CPT = ISNULL(@CPT+', ',' ')+@CPTCODE 
  FETCH NEXT FROM CPTCURSOR INTO @CPTVOUCHER, @CPTCODE  
END 
CLOSE CPTCURSOR 
DEALLOCATE CPTCURSOR
```

Then A

```
SELECT DISTINCT #VoucherData.Voucher_Number, CPT.CPTCODE 
FROM #VOUCHERDATA  
  LEFT JOIN @CPTTABLE CPT ON CPT.Voucher_Number=#VoucherData.Voucher_Number
```

As I said, I am sure there is something very simple I am missing here. What happens is I will run this code and end up with a result set with hundreds of rows usually, every single one of them is correct except the last one which always has a NULL value for CPT.

Comment: You are actually Inserted the final record in the CPTTABLE after the records for CurrentCPTVoucher have ended and the next cpt voucher has started.So the last CPT voucher will never be inserted into the CPTTABLE as there is no record to process after the last record

Comment: Do you know a good way to fix this issue by changing the logic of how the cursor processes the final voucher? I don't know enough about cursors.
My extremely poor solution is to do a         INSERT INTO #VoucherData  VALUES(99999999, 'FAKE') and then in the final select do a WHERE Voucher_Number<>99999999 . This way, there is a fake voucher number that doesn't mean anything as the last row (They are ordered by voucher number). I would like to fix the root of the problem though and not rely on something like this.

Comment: Add the insert statement after the end of your while loop as well. It should fix this problem. Although I would recommend getting rid of CURSOR and use temporary tables and loops if you want to stick with the logic.

Comment: That fixed it ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would normally be done using XML for the string aggregation:

```
select v.Voucher_Number, 
       stuff( (select ', ' + cpt
               from #VoucherData v2
               where v2.Voucher_Number = v.Voucher_Number
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as codes
from (select distinct Voucher_Number from #VoucherData) v;
```

You don't want to use cursors when there is a set-based approach for the same result set.

Comment: Problem using this method is that I am now getting lines with the same CPT codes repeated many many times.

I am fairly new to T-SQL, just started in January. I have never used any of the XML functions before.

Comment: @DrRedmond . . . I don't understand the comment.  The result should be one row per `Voucher_Number` with all the `cpt` codes on that vouches.  If there are duplicates within the list, then you can use `select distinct` in the subquery.

Comment: Gordon - I am sorry for not explaining more fully. 

I figured out why your method is not working for me, and it was because I was not using a select distinct in the STUFF(() subquery. The reason the CPT codes were repeating is because even though a voucher may only contain 1 CPT code, there was an additional field regarding service diagnosis's that could lead to the CPT code being repeated for each instance of a service diagnosis.

Thank you again for your help, this solution will make it not necessary to use the cursor anymore.

Comment: I'm going to check out your SQL/Excel book. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this instead of a cursor:

using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
select distinct 
    Voucher_Number
  , stuff((
    select distinct ', ' + i.cpt
      from #Voucherdata i
      where i.Voucher_number = t.Voucher_number
    for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,2,'')
from #Voucherdata t
```

Comment: Got this method to work - In the subquery you need to place distinct right after select, not before the i.cpt.  I am going to look more into this stuff function now. Thank you!

Comment: @DrRedmond Whoops, sorry for the misplaced `distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

you might not require to use cursor for this string aggregation, you can use query as below:

```
Select VoucherNumber,  stuff ((
    select ', ' + CPT from #VoucherData where VoucherNumber = t.VoucherNumber 
    for xml path('')
    ),1,2,'') as CPT
From #VoucherData t
Group by VoucherNumber
```

If it is SQL Server 2017, SQL Azure or PDW you can use String_Agg as below:

```
Select VoucherNumber, String_Agg(CPT, ', ') as CPT
    from #VoucherData
Group by VoucherNumber
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am on SQL Server 2008 R2 at the moment, 

The First method you showed above does return the correct number of rows, however in the CPT columns it will repeat the codes over and over, in some cases endlessly. 

I have only been coding with T-SQL for a few months and have never got into the XML features, I am sure there is something I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you have null values in CPT columns by any chance?

Comment: No, the table that the CPT code's are coming from is a dictionary table with no Null values. All the joins to that table are inner joins as well so there would be no nulls in the final temporary table the cursor is running off.